# Segmentation Fault in Simple C Calculator

Tags: c

I have run into a segmentation fault in a simple c calculator that I am trying to create.  The calculator is supposed to take in a formula with +, x, and square brackets and output the answer. The implementation is based on two arrays that work as stacks, an operand stack and a value stack. I am struggling to fix the segmentation fault.  I have attached the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void pushValStack(int stack[], int *top, int value){
   *top++;
   stack[*top] = value;
}

int popValStack(int stack[], int *top){
   *top--;
   return stack[*top];
}

void pushOpStack(char *stack[], int *top, char *value){
   *top++;
   stack[*top] = value;
}

char *popOpStack(char *stack[], int *top){
   *top--;
   return stack[*top];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   char *token;
   int tokenNumber = 1;
   int value[51];
   int *valueTop = 0;
   int valueOne,valueTwo;
   char *operand[51];
   int *operandTop = 0;
   char *operandOne;

   token = argv[tokenNumber];
   while (token != NULL){
      if (*token == '+' || *token == 'x' || *token == '['){
         pushOpStack(operand, operandTop, token);
      }
      else if (*token == ']'){
         while (*operand[*operandTop] != '['){
            operandOne = popOpStack(operand, operandTop);
            if (*operandOne == '+'){
               valueOne = popValStack(value, valueTop);
               valueTwo = popValStack(value, valueTop);
               pushValStack(value, valueTop, valueOne + valueTwo);
            }
            if (*operandOne == 'x'){
               valueOne = popValStack(value, valueTop);
               valueTwo = popValStack(value, valueTop);
               pushValStack(value, valueTop, valueOne * valueTwo);
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         pushValStack(value, valueTop, atoi(token));
      }
      tokenNumber++;
      token = argv[tokenNumber];
   }
   while (*operandTop != 0){
      operandOne = popOpStack(operand, operandTop);
      if (*operandOne == '+'){
         valueOne = popValStack(value, valueTop);
         valueTwo = popValStack(value, valueTop);
         pushValStack(value, valueTop, valueOne + valueTwo);
      }
      if (*operandOne == 'x'){
         valueOne = popValStack(value, valueTop);
         valueTwo = popValStack(value, valueTop);
         pushValStack(value, valueTop, valueOne * valueTwo);
      }
   }
   printf("\n%d",popValStack(value, valueTop));
}
```

Comment: I'd expect `*top++;  stack[*top] = value;` --> `stack[*top] = value; (*top)++; `.  It _looks_ like code has 2 issues: pre/post (*p)++ vs *p++, maybe more.
`

Comment: First step: check that `argc` tells you there are enough program arguments.

Comment: `*top++` is the same as `*(top++)` because of operator precedence. Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: `int *valueTop = 0;` looks suspicious. You are passing this pointer to be dereferenced in `pushValStack()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a number of `int*` variables, but never allocating any memory for them. They should be `int` instead, since they contain indexes into the stack.

```
int valueTop = 0;
int operandTop = 0;
```

Then you should use these variables, you don't need to dereference them. But when you pass them to functions that need to update the variables, you have to pass the address of the variable.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *token;
    int tokenNumber = 1;
    int value[51];
    int valueTop = 0;
    int valueOne,valueTwo;
    char *operand[51];
    int operandTop = 0;
    char *operandOne;

    token = argv[tokenNumber];
    while (token != NULL){
        if (*token == '+' || *token == 'x' || *token == '['){
            pushOpStack(operand, &operandTop, token);
        }
        else if (*token == ']'){
            while (*operand[operandTop] != '['){
                operandOne = popOpStack(operand, &operandTop);
                if (*operandOne == '+'){
                    valueOne = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
                    valueTwo = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
                    pushValStack(value, &valueTop, valueOne + valueTwo);
                }
                if (*operandOne == 'x'){
                    valueOne = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
                    valueTwo = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
                    pushValStack(value, &valueTop, valueOne * valueTwo);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            pushValStack(value, &valueTop, atoi(token));
        }
        tokenNumber++;
        token = argv[tokenNumber];
    }
    while (operandTop != 0){
        operandOne = popOpStack(operand, &operandTop);
        if (*operandOne == '+'){
            valueOne = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
            valueTwo = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
            pushValStack(value, &valueTop, valueOne + valueTwo);
        }
        if (*operandOne == 'x'){
            valueOne = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
            valueTwo = popValStack(value, &valueTop);
            pushValStack(value, &valueTop, valueOne * valueTwo);
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d",popValStack(value, &valueTop));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`operandTop` is a pointer variable of type `int*`. You initialize it to `0` (a null pointer) and never assign a different value to it. Any attempt to dereference it will cause undefined behavior, likely a segmentation fault.

I ran your program under a debugger with no command-line arguments, and it died on line 61, `while (*operandTop != 0){`